# htaccess mod_rewrite hostname

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, debian

How can i rewrite the domain url to a specific domain name if it didnt match it ..

Let's say i want it to only match example.com
and the visitor came from server ip (http://127.0.0.1/something/else) OR came from another domain (http://domain.com/something/else)

how can i rewrite the domain name and keep all the other parameters, just domain name to example.com ( result should be : http://example.com/somthing/else )

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1/something/else` isn't an IP address. Do you mean from a referring page/URL?

Comment: @nickhar You should have chosen the name ni[tpi]ckhar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R]
```