# SSL: HTTP www redirect to non www HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

sorry about links put can only post 2 beacuse i am new on the forum.

My problem is with my site https//freespinslista.se/ which is working fine but when i type in the web address field www.freespinslista.se I am coming to https://www.freespinslista.se/

I only have SSL for without www so I dont want traffic to https//www.freespinslista.se/ because then it gives  you a security warning.

I want www typers to go to http://www.freespinslista.se/ and there simply to redirect straight to https//freespinslista.se/ so that there will be no security warning.

HOW DO I MAKE www typers go to http and redirect to non www https while non www typers still goes to https?

my .htaccess looks like this:

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
  </IfModule>
```

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rewrite condition to HTTP_HOST. Look at this example [htaccess mod_rewrite hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021893/htaccess-mod-rewrite-hostname)

Comment: I am all new to this dont really know a lot of code language. What in my current htaccess should be altered to get all visitors straight to https:// freespinslista.se/? even if you are typing www.freespinslista.se